# Get latest timestamp from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries that I am pulling from a ticketing system. Each dictionary contains the name and timestamp of a ticket.

There are cases where multiple tickets are entered for the same user and I would like to filter this list to only append the 'latest' timestamp to the list, rather than all occurrences.

**Edit: I am looking to get a list of dictionaries returned that includes a list of all unique Name values with the largest Date value.**

I have included updated list examples that might make it easier to work with.

My function that gathers the data is:

```
def get_onboarded_users():
    # The ticket that it is retrieving looks something like this:
    # "(IT) - Onboarding Initiated - Bill Bob"
    print("Collecting Onboarded Users", end="")
    url = 'https://********************/api/v3/requests'
    headers = {"authtoken": "*********************************"}
    rtn = []
    input_data = '''{
        "list_info": {
            "row_count": 5000,
            "start_index": 1,
            "sort_field": "subject",
            "sort_order": "asc",
            "get_total_count": true,
            "search_fields": {
                "subject": "(IT) - Onboarding Initiated"
            }
        }
    }'''
    params = {'input_data': input_data}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    i = json.loads(response.text)
    user_requests = i['requests']
    onboarded_users = {}
    for user_request in user_requests:
        subject = user_request['subject'].upper()
        create_date = req['created_time']['value']
        user = subject.split(' - ')
        onboarded_users['Name'] = user[2]
        onboarded_users['Date'] = int(create_date) / 1000
        rtn.append(onboarded_users.copy())
    print(" - Complete")
    return rtn
```

My API call returns something that looks like this:

```
[
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "1" },
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "2" },
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "3" },
    { "Name": "Bill Bob", "Date": "4" },
    { "Name": "Bill Bob", "Date": "7" },
    { "Name": "Sam Jackson", "Date": "1" }
]
```

and would like it to look like this:

```
[
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "3" },
    { "Name": "Bill Bob", "Date": "7" },
    { "Name": "Sam Jackson", "Date": "1" }
]
```

Comment: You should clarify that you want the latest for each unique user name, if that's what you actually want. Not just all items that have the latest timestamp (which is what all current answers seem to be assuming).

Comment: Thanks, I will update the question. I feel like I did make that clear, but a better look at it and it appears I didn't make it clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
import itertools

lst = [
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "1" },
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "2" },
    { "Name": "Rob Smith", "Date": "3" },
    { "Name": "Bill Bob", "Date": "4" },
    { "Name": "Bill Bob", "Date": "7" },
    { "Name": "Sam Jackson", "Date": "1" }
]

res = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x["Name"]):
    res.append(max(group, key= lambda y: y['Date']))
    
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'Name': 'Rob Smith', 'Date': '3'}, 
    {'Name': 'Bill Bob', 'Date': '7'}, 
    {'Name': 'Sam Jackson', 'Date': '1'}
]
```

As an alternative, You can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
res = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].max().reset_index().to_dict('records')
print(res)


# [{'Name': 'Bill Bob', 'Date': '7'},
#  {'Name': 'Rob Smith', 'Date': '3'},
#  {'Name': 'Sam Jackson', 'Date': '1'}]
```

Comment: This is only printing the dictionary with the largest date value out of the entire list, however, what I am looking to do is retrieve all dictionaries from the list and only IF there is duplicate dictionaries with an equal key value of "Name" it will pick the one with the largest timestamp.

Comment: @stryker0808, I run with your list of dict and work correctly, see the update. Unless you input another format.

Comment: @stryker0808, this work for you, If you have another question ask exactly your question.

Comment: This doesn't find the latest by user.

Comment: You are correct that it is working the way I provided the list. The list I have is in the exact same format, however, only seems to return a single dictionary that has the highest date value. The list I have has over 500 records, would this have any effect on it?

Comment: @jarmod, what do you mean? I can't understand.  'find the latest by user'?

Comment: The chance of multiple tickets being generated at exactly the same millisecond from multiple users is low. It seems very likely therefore that the  OP actually wants the latest ticket per user.

Comment: I have updated the question and included a more ideal way the list looks before and the way it should look after. Hope that helps!

Comment: It's definitely unfortunate that the OP originally copy/pasted the latest timestamp which gave the erroneous impression that the requirement was simply to find all dicts that had the latest timestamp. But reading between the lines would hopefully have identified the actual requirement.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, I will know better for next time to make things more clear - I take that responsibility for the incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks I'mahdi that edit is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @stryker0808, You're welcome, I add second solution with `pandas`. have a good time ;)